# What is the difference between Chrome speech API and google speech API?

Tags: google-chrome, speech-to-text, speech, google-speech-api

I have been trying to integrate speech recognition stt in my project and after trying out various of them I found chrome's native web speech API to be the best. How is it when compared to google's speech API in terms of performance  and accuracy.

Comment: What language / platform are you using?

Comment: Javascript/node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Web Speech API is a W3C supported specification that allows browser vendors to supply a speech recognition engine of their choosing (be it local or cloud-based) that backs an API you can use directly from the browser without having to worry about API limits and the like.

The Google Speech API is a cloud-based solution that allows you to use Google's speech software outside of a browser. It also provides broader language support and can transcribe longer audio files. It requires billing information for testing purposes and charges after 30 days of trial.